# How to ensure each DIV appears on it's own without overlapping

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I am using code-behind to populate a repeater (please disregard inline css, it will be changed once I have it working correctly):

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptContent">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <div style="width: 85%; margin: 0 auto; background: #000000; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid yellow;">
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div style="float: left; width: 34%; border: 1px solid green;">
            <div style="width: 100%; padding: 2%; text-align: center;">
                <img src="http://westmedgroup.com/<%# Eval("Image").ToString() %>" />
                <h2 style="color: #CA006C;"><%# Eval("Physician Name").ToString() %></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="float: right; width: 64%; border: 1px solid red;">
            <div style="width: 45%; padding: 2%; text-align: left; float: left;">
                <div>
                    <div style="font-family: 'consolas'; font-size: 22px; font-weight: bold; background: url(theImages/topmenu.png) no-repeat; width: 260px; height: 47px;">
                        <span style="position: relative; top: 18%; left: 8%;">SPECIALTIES</span>
                    </div>
                    <div style="background: url(theImages/botmenu.png) repeat-y; width: 260px;">
                        <div style="padding-left: 20px;">
                            <ul style="padding: 8px; margin: 0; list-style-type: none; color: #0072C7;">
                                <li style="font-family: 'consolas'; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; padding: 6px; text-transform: uppercase;"><%# Eval("Specialty1").ToString() %></li>
                                <li style="font-family: 'consolas'; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; padding: 6px; text-transform: uppercase;"><%# Eval("Specialty2").ToString() %></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div style="font-family: 'consolas'; font-size: 22px; font-weight: bold; background: url(theImages/topmenu.png) no-repeat; width: 260px; height: 47px;">
                        <span style="position: relative; top: 18%; left: 8%;">LOCATIONS</span>
                    </div>
                    <div style="background: url(theImages/botmenu.png) repeat-y; width: 260px;">
                        <div style="padding-left: 20px;">
                            <ul style="padding: 8px; margin: 0; list-style-type: none; color: #0072C7;">
                                <li style="font-family: 'consolas'; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; padding: 6px; text-transform: uppercase;"><%# Eval("Office1").ToString() %></li>
                                <li style="font-family: 'consolas'; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; padding: 6px; text-transform: uppercase;"><%# Eval("Office2").ToString() %></li>
                                <li style="font-family: 'consolas'; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; padding: 6px; text-transform: uppercase;"><%# Eval("Office3").ToString() %></li>
                                <li style="font-family: 'consolas'; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; padding: 6px; text-transform: uppercase;"><%# Eval("Office4").ToString() %></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="width: 45%; padding: 2%; text-align: left; float: right;">
                <div>
                    <div style="font-family: 'consolas'; font-size: 22px; font-weight: bold; background: url(theImages/topmenu.png) no-repeat; width: 260px; height: 47px;">
                        <span style="position: relative; top: 18%; left: 8%;">GENDER</span>
                    </div>
                    <div style="background: url(theImages/botmenu.png) repeat-y; width: 260px;">
                        <div style="padding-left: 20px;">
                            <ul style="padding: 8px; margin: 0; list-style-type: none; color: #0072C7;">
                                <li style="font-family: 'consolas'; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; padding: 6px; text-transform: uppercase;"><%# Eval("Gender").ToString() %></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div style="font-family: 'consolas'; font-size: 22px; font-weight: bold; background: url(theImages/topmenu.png) no-repeat; width: 260px; height: 47px;">
                        <span style="position: relative; top: 18%; left: 8%;">PHONE NUMBER</span>
                    </div>
                    <div style="background: url(theImages/botmenu.png) repeat-y; width: 260px;">
                        <div style="padding-left: 20px;">
                            <ul style="padding: 8px; margin: 0; list-style-type: none; color: #0072C7;">
                                <li style="font-family: 'consolas'; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; padding: 6px; text-transform: uppercase;"><%# Eval("PhoneNum").ToString() %></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div style="font-family: 'consolas'; font-size: 22px; font-weight: bold; background: url(theImages/topmenu.png) no-repeat; width: 260px; height: 47px;">
                        <span style="position: relative; top: 18%; left: 8%;">FAX NUMBER</span>
                    </div>
                    <div style="background: url(theImages/botmenu.png) repeat-y; width: 260px;">
                        <div style="padding-left: 20px;">
                            <ul style="padding: 8px; margin: 0; list-style-type: none; color: #0072C7;">
                                <li style="font-family: 'consolas'; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; padding: 6px; text-transform: uppercase;"><%# Eval("FaxNum").ToString() %></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div style="width: 260px; text-align: right;"><a class="loginButton" href="#">View Full Profile</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        </div>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

What I am looking to do is achieve the following so each physician has his/her own box within the yellow border DIV:

[image]

But what I am getting in FireFox (As you can see the the yellow box is not wrapping each DIV-child group:

[image]

What I am getting in IE is:

[image]

How can I achieve it? I am guessing somewhere the repeater is being parsed incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

at the first look, i believe you need to `clear` the `floats` you are using.

```
<div style="clear:both">
    <div style="float:right;"></div>
    <div style="float:left;"></div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both">
    <div style="float:right;"></div>
    <div style="float:left;"></div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both">
    <div style="float:right;"></div>
    <div style="float:left;"></div>
</div>
```

if you dont use clear:both (or similar techniques), the parent divs will have no height, as the children using float, aquire no height.

if you cannot use a wrapping div, you can also just break the floating with a inline technique

```
<div style="float:left"></div>
<br style="clear:both" />
```

currently preferred solutions are to use the pseudo selector `:after`, where you will need some proper block style css. (copied from backbone)

```
.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  display: table;
  line-height: 0;
  content: "";
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

a simple tutorial on this, showing the grids, http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Comment: I am guessing I have to use a few more DIVs to what I already have?

Comment: i would suggest you the last method, using the `.clearfix` css class. you then just have to add it to some parent div that contains `float:left` or `float:right`. just `<div class="clearfix">` will fix it

Comment: I think I have it working so far. I will work on it and see how far I can go :) Thanks.